# How to add jsf components to taglib programmatically

Tags: jsf, taglib

I was wondering if it's possible to add JSF components to the tag library programmatically? 
I'm implementing a plug-in mechanism in our application. And now, if I create a JSF component in the plug-in, I need to change the components taglib xml file in the main application, which is not the goal.
I'd rather like to put a components taglib xml file inside a plug-in which is then handled by the main application. Is there any way to do that?

The reason why I'm asking this is the following:
In our application, we send secure messages through a web interface. The messages are created by filling out forms, which are, in most cases, generated. But some forms have special behavior and we don't want to release the whole application if a new 'special form' is implemented, so we decided to put these in plug-ins.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: Do you have any news on this issue? I'm also interested in this.

Comment: Apparently not, it doesn't seem to be possible at all.